# Load Halfword into register

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-word

I need to read from stored value two ints. 
So I've got stored  them in one 32bit register as a hex.

For example: 0x50002 is int x=5; int y=2;

I have a task to write a function in mips and one of the arguments of that function is "int xy" where, int x is stored in upper 16 bits and y in lower 16 bits of xy argument. And this argument is passed through $a1 and then I want use this x or y for further computation

I loaded these address into $a0 and I want to have a value "a" in $a1

li $a1, 0x50002

lhu $a0, ($a1)

Comment: `($a1)` is a memory reference. It's unclear why you even use that. If you want to split a 32 bit register into two, use shifts and masks. If you have the value in memory then yes, you can use `lhu`.

Comment: integers in registers are in binary, not hex.  Hex is a text serialization format for binary.  But yes, `lhu` to zero-extend a half-word from memory into a register, or `lh` to sign-extend.

Comment: Please learn to use Edit link under your question to keep all clarifications in one place.

Answer (score 0):

If `int xy` is a function arg, then its *value* is in `$a0` and you have to unpack it.

The easy way is with `xy >> 16` and `xy & 0xffff`.

Storing to the stack and then reloading with two `lhu` instructions is another less efficient way.  I don't know why you have any static storage allocated (a label like `xy:` in `.data`), that's unnecessary.

> 0x50002 is int a=1; int b=2;

That's a value to be unpacked, *not an address*. `0x50002` isn't a multiple of 4, so it can't be the starting address of a 32-bit `int`.

Also, you were talking about packing two 16-bit integers into a word; that would be `unsigned short a, b;`.

(If you had signed `short` data in memory, you'd use `lh` instead of `lhu`.)

But the upper 16 bits are `5`, not `1`, so it doesn't match either.

Answer (score 0):

To get x into $a0 after `li $a1, 0x50002`, do:

```
sra $a0, $a1, 16       # $a0 = right shifted top 16 bits of $a1 i.e. x
```

To clear the top 16 bits of $a0, leaving the value of y, do:

```
andi $a0, $a0, 0xffff  # $ now $a0 only contains y
```

Finally, to sign extend the value of y to 32 bits, do:

```
sll $a0, $a0, 16       # move y's sign bit to $a0's sign bit
sra $a0, $a0, 16       # arithmetic shift y to its original position
```

Comment: `sra` is an arithmetic right shift that shifts in copies of the the sign bit, not zeros.  So you're sign-extending the high half but zero-extending the low half with `andi`.  That's inconsistent; `srl` would make more sense.

Comment: added sign extension for y as well as x.